# Составить список переменных и массивов в Microsoft Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio

Есть ли в Microsoft Visual Studio Express возможность получить список всех объявленных в программе переменных и массивов? 
Т.е. выбрал пункт в меню, и получил список.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нет